# How to refer to active browser window and click in something there?

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

I'm quite new in Python, and I'm creating a robot to export some reports from a system that is in Silverlight. Therefore, I can't use elements of the page to click/select/insert dates, etc.

Then, my solution was using `pyautogui` to move the mouse, click on the right buttons and save the files...

The process is:

-Select dates of the report

-Click on the "team" I need the report for

-Click on preview button (a new window opens here)

-Maximise this window which contains the report

-Click on 'Export' button (drop-down)

-Select 'Export to CSV'

And then, via code, get last downloaded file and move it into the folder where I save the reports.

The bottleneck on this is: sometimes, due to an unknown reason, 'Export' button is 20/'30 pixels aside. It means that the robot clicks in nowhere, and the code stops since there is no "last downloaded file" to handle.
I already noticed this second window (where the report opens) is not in Silverlight. It's simple HTML. I know I could use some methods in `selenium` to select the Export/Export to CSV option (similarly as I've done to login into this system). But my problem is: how do I refer to this new window?

The code I'm using refers to the main page using `selenium.wedriver` but I couldn't find a way to refer to the new window (that is closed after I downloaded the CSV. Then I click again in "Preview" and another window opens, and the process repeat hundreds of times)...

```
wsite='https://WEBSITE TO EXTRACT'
driver = webdriver.Ie('C:\\MyFolder\\IEDriverServer.exe')
driver.get(wsite) #opens the site
driver.find_element_by_id('userNameInput').send_keys('USERNAME')
driver.find_element_by_id ('passwordInput').send_keys('PASSWORD')
driver.find_element_by_id('submitButton').click()
```

Then, there are a lots of lines of code (where the mouse clicks where it's needed...

```
pyautogui.moveTo(1846,1000,intervaltoclick)#Preview button
pyautogui.click()
time.sleep(3)
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
if i<1:
    time.sleep(10+t)
else:
    time.sleep(5+(t/5))
pyautogui.moveTo(566,52,intervaltoclick)#Export
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.moveTo(603,205,intervaltoclick)#Save as CSV
pyautogui.click()
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.moveTo(1270,1025,intervaltoclick)#close window
pyautogui.click()
```

Would someone have any idea on how can I do that?

Comment: You can try to keep the selenium object of IE browser that you used for login. You can keep it hidden if you don't want to show on a screen. You can than try to loop through the IE windows and switch to desired window. Here is a helpful link which shows the examples to switch the window. https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/

Comment: Thanks for that @Deepak-MSFT. I sorted it using switch window. I just didn't know the command switch window would change the driver's focus... Now, I managed to iterate with it. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to keep the selenium object of IE browser that you used for login. You can keep it hidden if you don't want to show on a screen. You can than try to loop through the IE windows and switch to desired window.

```
 Set<String> allWindowHandles = browser.getWindowHandles();

       for(String handle : allWindowHandles)
       {
           System.out.println("Window handle - > " + handle);
           browser.switchTo().window(handle);
           System.out.println(browser.getTitle());
       }
```

Here is a helpful link which shows the examples to switch the window.

[Selenium WebDriver Switch Window Commands](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/)